# Bengali Writing with polyglossia in beamer

Tags: beamer, polyglossia, presentations

I tried using the [polyglossia](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) package to make a presentation in Bengali with [beamer](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Bangla MN}
\title{\LARGE \textbf বong একাডেমী }

\author{Amit Majumder}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

but it gives the error message:

```
Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Bengal(polyglossia) Please define \bengalifont with \newfontfamily. \select@language {bengali}
```

What to do?

Comment: Try `\setmainfont` instead of `\newfontfamily\bengalifont`.

Answer (score 3):

It works with the serif option because then the roman font is used instead of sans serif:

```
\documentclass[10pt,serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Bangla MN}
\title{\LARGE \textbf বong একাডেমী }

\author{Amit Majumder}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It works !, Thanks a lot.